# How do you get Facebook like box to show in web page?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

The Answer has yet to be addressed. How do you get the Facebook like box to show on a web page with out being logged into Facebook? The company has a Facebook page all setting are set to full public view. I am using the most current codes created by Facebook. I have tried using old iframe code from another site that this works on and replaced all the url instances and it still was not visable. The sites Url is http://www.magnoliabranch.com, to see what I am talking about make sure you are not logged into Facebook, Load the site - no like box, open new tab log into Facebook refresh site tab ta-DA like box appears. I need a fix for this ASAP to many hours have be spent on chasing code, java, and HTML. Thanks for the Help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a website which will help you.  Please visit here.

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example made from following [Facebooks developer guidelines for the Like button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/). Place this right after the opening body tag:

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>

    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

    <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/MagnoliaRV" data-layout="standard" data-action="like"></div>
```